# How to adjust dataframe column names in streamlit

Tags: python, dataframe, streamlit

I am trying to display only selected columns from the pandas dataframe. logic is working but columns come with extra characters added to them.

Selected columns come inside Parentheses, quotes and coma. I got stuck on finding from where does it come and how to get rid of it.

Please Help.

```
import pandas as pd
import streamlit as st


df = pd.read_csv('data/AUDCAD_1h.csv')

st.sidebar.header('Data Filter')
col = st.sidebar.multiselect("Select any column",
                             df.columns)
if not col:
    data = df.copy()
else:
    data = df[col].values
    data = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=[col])
st.write(data)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of

```
if not col:
    data = df.copy()
else:
    data = df[col].values
    data = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=[col])
st.write(data)
```

N.B. Streamlit multiselect option returns a list.

Just use:

```
if not col:
    data = df.copy()
else:
    data = data[col]
st.write(data)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also skip the if statement by selecting all columns as a default.

`st.dataframe` can provide more functionalities such as columns configuration.

```
import pandas as pd
import streamlit as st


df = pd.read_csv('data/AUDCAD_1h.csv')

st.sidebar.header('Data Filter')
col = st.sidebar.multiselect("Select any column",
                             df.columns, defualt=df.columns)
st.dataframe(data[col])
```